# ImportError at /mysite/ No module named bleach

Tags: python, django

I tried to google this tirelessly and couldn't get help at all.

I just `pip install bleach` and when I tried using in my **views.py**, `import bleach` it says **ImportError at /mysite/
No module named bleach**

I installed from this directory in *command prompt*:

**(env) C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\env\Scripts\myproject\mysite>pip install bleach**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tried installing it with admin privileges?

Comment: Just did and it worked! Thank you plenty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing as admin screws the whole point of using [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

When using virtualenv you are setting a custom place for your libraries. You can use pip install my-package from anywhere after you activated the env and it will place the files in the same place.

While you are in your env try pip_freeze to see what is currently installed in your virtual env.

If you are interested in troubleshooting this issue, run the freeze and check if you are using env as you should.